# Switching from SYSTEM to Administrator

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, user-accounts

I have remote CommandLine/Powershell access to a Windows Server as NT Authority/SYSTEM user, I need to be Administrator user but whatever I do like start a new process, I am unable to drop to Administrator user, tried executing scripts, used runas etc, everything runs as SYSTEM,

What can do to drop to Administrator shell from SYSTEM?

Comment: many thanks, I managed to run as pid of explorer to switch to administrator using Advanced Run, using administrator directly was not working @DrMoishePippik great suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a third-party tool, such as Nirsoft's free [*Advanced Run*](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/advanced_run.html) (below), or an [alternative](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/run-program-as-trustedinstaller-locked-registry-keys-files/#advancedrun). These tools let you choose to run an application as a low-level user, Administrator, or even TrustedInstaller.

[image: Nirsoft's Advanced Run]

Note that you might need to select names from a list on that PC, such as ///<user_name>.